# Weak entity vs subclass, what is the difference?

Tags: database, database-design, entity, relational-database

What is the difference between a weak entity and a subclass?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In extended ER models that support subclassing the answer you are looking for probably has to do with some assumptions about keys in each case:

- If entity A is a subclass then the key (or *a* key) of A consists of exactly the same attributes as a key in another entity B.
- If entity A is a weak entity then some *subset* of the key (or *a* key) of A consists of the same attributes as a key in another entity B.

Like much of ER modelling, these things are conventions of notation that aren't always very precisely defined or consistently used. The use of the term subclass may even be questionable - many users of ER models will use the term subtype instead.

You tagged your question with `relational-database` but these are definitely not relational model concepts, they are ER modelling concepts.

Comment: I'm glad you flagged the difference between ER modeling and relational modeling.  The prevailing view seems to be that they are the same thing.  I think something valuable would be lost if the opposite view went away.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this are not uniform across all the available literature.  This is the way I learned it.

A weak entity requires a relationship with another entity in order to have an identity.  Let's take orders and line items within an order.  Using only natural keys, the identity of a line item is order number and line number, eg order 54321 line 3.  You can't have a line item that isn't part of an order, because it doesn't have an identity.

Of course, you can always use the autonumber feature of the DBMS to assign an apparent identity to every row when it's inserted.  But that doesn't prove that the entity has an identity in the real world.

A subclass is not a separate entity, but a subset of the instances in some other entity.  Consider Pets, Dogs, and Cats.  There may be attributes that pertain to dogs but not cats and vice versa.  (there are plenty of subclasses of pets besides dogs and cats, but I'm just keeping it simple).